# What is the meaning of `object` in this Kotlin example?

Tags: kotlin

On the first line of the following code example, what is the meaning of "`object`"? Being new to Kotlin I expected I'd be able to change it to any name (e.g. `callback`) but that doesn't seem to work.

```
service.getUserList().enqueue(object: Callback<List<User>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<User>>, t: Throwable) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<User>>, response: Response<List<User>>) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`object` is the reserved word for declaring a new instance of an object. It is the way kotlin handles annonymous classes

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

The `enqueue` method has an argument with a name, and that argument is from the type `Callback`

If you want to name that callbak then

```
val callback = object: Callback..
```

Since this is the equivalent of a Java anonymous class remember the anonymous class wouldnt have a name neither.

What the reserved word is doing there is saying `instantiate an object of the type Callback`, hence the `object` and the `:`